# Displaying image stream of an IPcam

Tags: wpf, performance, image, streaming

I'm currently developing a WPF application where one of the controls displays a stream of images; much like any webcam. These images originate of an IP camera and can only be accessed by an HTTP Url, which is fixed and always the sames. Now capturing the images is no problem, via

```
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.UriSource = uri;
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
    bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    return bitmapImage;
```

This much works. The problem arises when I attempt to hook up several cameras (more than 6), the application chokes and eventually crashes. All cameras run on a separate thread btw.

I've identified the basic problem: creating a (highlevel?) bitmap eats too much resources as I need the app to process about 600 images/sec in real-time (about 30Mb/sec) eventually.

In a nutshell, i'm looking for a way to make this retrieval/rendering process a lot more efficient.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Forgot to mention perhaps, im working in .NET 4 WPF, the camera itself is a Mobotix M12, accessed by ethernet.

Comment: I know Mobotix and also working on .Net 4 in WPF. Have similar problems.

Comment: @Nasenbaer: did you ever manage to solve them?

Comment: In my case I could solve it by adding a own UI class to update the image in less interval than the camera streams the frames. I've used a memory converter because internally I am working additional with default Bitmap in case of ImageSource. Also take a look to the Garbage collector `GC.Collect`. What is memory doing in your case? In my case all is working. But the situation is different to yours. I have not several Mobotix cameras to test :-) If you want to share your code I can try to fix your problem by SVN or FTP.

Comment: @Nasenbaer: a colleague managed to fix it with aForge: http://code.google.com/p/aforge/ It has a lot of functionality and works out of the box... Take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very late update and for anyone still interested - we managed an implementation with the aForge framework http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/framework

While dated, it can do these kind of things out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I get this right, each camera has a framerate of 100 fps? (you mention 600 images/second for 6 cams). 
With some profiling you could identify the bottleneck?